Weird orbiting after updating blender
After the update, orbiting in Blender sometimes started behaving strangely; this happens occasionally after switching from orthographic view to perspective view. Sometimes the object just disappears from view, and I have to zoom out to see it again.
Here's how it looks:
https://jumpshare.com/s/rE7rgNUjXpAbImFm4isp

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
